# Adding a non-existent tag to question gives non-informative error message

Tags: bug, tags, error-message

I was trying to add a tag called seed_fu (referring to a [gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) with a same name) but this tag was not created yet. I got an error message which said that

> Please enter no more than 5 tags

... while having exactly 5 tags entered (one of them was the non-existent `seed_fu`-tag). I guess the real problem was that I was not allowed to add a non-existent tag so the error message was a bit confusing.

Situation described on a picture:
[image]

Comment: For why you can't do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: @Zizouz212 The question is a bit confusing, but I think he's trying to say that he should get a message saying something like "you do not have the privilege to create new tags" instead of the current message.

Comment: @TroyT: [tag:seed] is an actual tag. And due to the way it is parsed and processed, it is seen as 6 tags hence the particular message. An underscore is not valid in a tag. Prioritizing a message indicating that the tag list contained invalid characters would have been more useful.

Comment: @TroyT yes, that is exactly what I meant. `You do not have the privilege to create new tags` or even sth like `The tag list contains an invalid character` would be much more logical. The 5+ tags count was another confusing factor for me.